# What is a good Azure architecture for Web App Services

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-web-app-service

I have been researching for a couple days and looking at pluralsight courses but I Can't seem to find a decent answer on how to setup a proper Azure infrastructure.

I have a client app, api backend, and a database as a core of my overall application. I know I need 2 different Web App services and an SQL database.

I also have a need to only allow access to all 3 from our company's IP address.

I'm getting lost with all the VNET and VPN talk and I am wondering if that is even required. Is it considered good to do IP restrictions and call it a day? Should I add an Application Gateway infront of the client application none the less?

If VNETs are required, is it a must to do site-to-site? (don't think we have the authority to do that) If not, how do we access the backend services like the database and API if everything is locked down?

Any help is appreciated because there is too much information and I can't seem to make sense of any of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on both the purpose of your client application, web application and database, as well as the capabilities that currently exist within your organisation. Have you had a look at the references architectures Microsoft has as a starting point ?

If you are looking at a fairly simple application, deployed to Azure with minimal internal only use, then use something like this reference architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/vpn. You can actually simplify that a little further by removing the load balancers etc if you think traffic will be generally low.

If you are looking for an external application that can only be managed internally, you should adopt something similar to this reference architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/n-tier/n-tier-sql-server. Maybe even add a VPN component to the management jump box similar to this architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/vpn.

Even this, however may be too complicated for your use case. If your application is pretty basic, is secured using username/password or identity federation, and has low risk data associated with it, then just the basic web application architecture would do fine, just read through the various considerations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/basic-web-app